# Slow HornetQ Producer when Queue is persistent

Tags: java, jboss, queue, hornetq

I have tried with Persistent Queue in horntQ. I have made two separate examples (Producer, Consumer). My consumer is working well but the Producer is taking too much time to finish sending message. I have run both separately as well as together. What could be the problem?
my code is:

```
public  class HornetProducer implements Runnable{

    Context ic = null;
    ConnectionFactory cf = null;
    Connection connection =  null;
    Queue queue = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer publisher =  null;
    TextMessage message = null;
    int messageSent=0;

     public synchronized static Context getInitialContext()throws javax.naming.NamingException {

            Properties p = new Properties( );
            p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES," org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhosts:1099");

            return new javax.naming.InitialContext(p);
        }  

    public HornetProducer()throws Exception{            

        ic = getInitialContext();
        cf = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
        queue = (Queue)ic.lookup("queue/testQueue2");
        connection = cf.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);        
        publisher = session.createProducer(queue);
        connection.start();

    }

    public void publish(){      
        try{        

            message = session.createTextMessage("Hello!");
            System.out.println("StartDate: "+new Date());

            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){                   
                 messageSent++;              
                 publisher.send(message);                
            }
            System.out.println("EndDate: "+new Date());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in Consume: "+ e.getMessage());
        }           
    }

    public void run(){
         publish();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        new HornetProducer().publish();    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending these messages persistently, and non transactionally. What means, each message sent has to be completed individually.

That means for each message you send, you have to make a network round trip to the server, and wait it finish persistency before you can send another message.

If you had multiple producers on this situation, hornetq would batch both producers and you would save a lot of time. (i.e. the server will batch many write requests).

If you want to speed up the sending of a single producer, you should use transactions probably.

for example:

I - Change your session to transactioned:

```
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTIONED);
```

II - commit every N messages:

```
   for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){                   
         messageSent++;              
         publisher.send(message);  
         if (messageSent % 1000 == 0) session.commit();              
    }
    session.commit();
```

You could also disable sync on Persistent messages. (Sending them asynchronously).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So which approach is better : Journal-sync to false or doing a per session batch as you suggested. Assuming there is only one session and all producers synchronize to use the same session ?

Comment: It all depends on your needs. setting journal-sync to false will make the system to stop syncing and you could eventually miss data in case of failures. the best approach is to batch transactions... send multiple messages on a single commit. consume multiple messages (acks) on single commit.

Comment: Does this apply to embedded and core api (not using jms)? I don't have a connection object, only ClientSessionFactory. I see a method, createTransactedSession(), is that what I would use in my case?

Comment: It does actually...just translate these things to the CoreAPI and you have the same semantics.