# HornetQ performance profiling

Tags: performance, hornetq

I'm using the hornetq-core-client api 2.4.0.Final, adding message with this code:

```
            ClientMessage clientMessage = _producerClientSession.createMessage(true);
            clientMessage.putStringProperty(MESSAGE_KEY, message);
            _clientProducer.send(clientMessage);
```

I'm reusing ClientSession and ClientProducer as mentioned in the docs. During profiling, we see this taking an average of 400+ ms. Does this seem right? It seems slow. We also have installed AIO on and running on ubuntu.

EDIT:
Here is the output for "iostat -d -x 1" while enqueueing was taking 600ms on avg

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00  596.00     0.00  2568.00     8.62     1.20    2.01    0.00    2.01   0.04   2.40

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    44.00    0.00  611.00     0.00 12904.00    42.24     0.10    0.17    0.00    0.17   0.05   2.80

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00  642.00     0.00  2916.00     9.08     0.02    0.03    0.00    0.03   0.03   2.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00  648.00     0.00  2900.00     8.95     0.03    0.04    0.00    0.04   0.04   2.80
```

EDIT #2
We updated our config to include:

```
    Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
    configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    configuration.setJournalSyncTransactional(false);
```

And for creating ClientSessionFactory to:

```
ClientSessionFactory sf = null;
  try {
    hornetQServer.start();
    ServerLocator serverLocator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName()));
    serverLocator.setBlockOnDurableSend(false);
    serverLocator.setProducerWindowSize(100000);

    serverLocator.setBlockOnAcknowledge(false);
    ClientSessionFactory sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();
```

The send time is now less than one millisecond. Are any of these settings unsafe, or not recommended for typical situations?

Comment: your system will never sync on the disk. In case of a failure you may lose messages that are still on the buffer but have been acked already. It depends on how strict you need to be. if you can afford eventually losing a few messages it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a single producer, a persistent message has to be persisted on the disk, and synced to your disk.

the client will block until all of that is happening.

The server is programmed to manage multiple producers and use most of your hardware, but if you only have one producer your performance will be maxed out by your network latency + your disk sync speed.

So for a single producer, sending a persistent message non transactionally (every send is a sync) it does sound right.

Edit: Also look at the set/getJournalBufferTimeout_AIO and set/getJournalBufferTimeout_NIO at ConfigurationImpl. Those are the values that are sent to the TimedBuffer before the server syncs data on disk waiting for other clients to sync at the same time.

Comment: So you mean rate of 2 writes per second to disk is about right ? I would expect a disc latency to be in ~10 ms and not ~500 ms. Please correct me.

Comment: Thanks Clebert. added some iostat output to the OP.

Comment: How many messages are you sending?

The system will try to use sleep(nanoSeconds) on TimedBuffer... there's a check that will go back to simple spinning if your kernel doesn't support real time. In certain cases nanoSleep will make to up to half second.. So for a very few messages you could expect a low response if you don't support real time.

Comment: Have you seen this question already?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304136/slow-hornetq-producer-when-queue-is-persistant

Comment: Yes, saw that post, and would like to try that, but we're using core, and embedded, and I don't see a way to set that using core api. If you have pointers to that please share. Also, we are sending 350 messages per second, we're using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 64 bit. So I would think it would support real time, but I'm not exactly sure (and not sure what that really means).

Comment: @Clebert Also except a very few messages, every message is taking hundreds of ms in enqueue. While disk utilization and wait time in disk queue as per iostat is negligible. So i would guess even if i batch i will be masking the problem instead of pointing to what exactly HornetQ is doing that is taking ~600ms for queueing every 300 byte message.

Comment: Look at a thread dump on the server at the time this is happening. I just did a test here and it worked fine. Maybe you changed some of the defaults?

at this time I would recommend you to open a forum post on the HornetQ user's forum and post a running example.

From the POV of Stack Overflow this question has been answered.

Comment: Since you are working with Embedded.. .look at the set/getJournalBufferTimeout_AIO and set/getJournalBufferTimeout_NIO at ConfigurationImpl. Those are the values that are sent to the TimedBuffer before the server syncs data on disk waiting for other clients to sync at the same time.

Comment: I'll look at those. I've edited the OP with new configuration changes that have reduced the enqueueing time to about a millisecond. Any concerns with those settings?